# How to get the film or reddish type of look?

Tags: dslr, film, color

I've been trying to achieve this affect, but it's way too difficult. The picture could be shot on using film, but I've seen the photographer (Marcus Hyde) use a DSLR. The look I am going for is the colors and the reddish or orange tone. I have taken pictures like this, but when I move different sliders like split tone or temperature it still won't come out like this. Is there a specific type of film or is just good editing? What film gives these colors or these photos occur when developing?

Comment: "Do u know what film gives these colors or these photos occur when developing?"   **Are you saying you want to use a film camera and get the same look as the image that was taken on a digital camera?** Your question is very confusing as you are mixing film and digital terminology and not being clear on your objective. This may be a  "how do i get this digital filter" question and as such may be closed as not appropriate for SE.  Or it is about film?  ?

Comment: This image w/ film: http://www.fujifilm.com/products/quicksnap/lineup/superia/

Comment: By saying "moving slider", I am pretty sure that the OP is trying to match film rendering with digital software

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blog: http://marcushydemedia.com/index2.html - Canon 5D II, sunlight and flash. He just takes the photo and that's how it comes out. He not into post processing it's natural. He has workshops and accepts questions if you want to contact him.

[Marcus Hyde YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/richylocsfilmer/videos?disable_polymer=1&app=desktop).

How it's Done Channel - "[The Marcus Hyde Interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4FtIKNmNXw&app=desktop)" (1 hr 3 min.)

---

[image: Marcus Hyde InstaGram]

I see no post processing.

---

If you have a photo that you want to copy the color scheme from you can try this:

- "[How To Replicate The Color Palette From Any Photo Or Famous Painting In Seconds In Photoshop](https://www.slrlounge.com/replicate-color-palette-photo-famous-painting-seconds-photoshop/)" or "[Matching Color Schemes Across Images in Adobe Photoshop CS4](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1395931)".
- The Pantone Studio Tool - [Android](https://www.pantone.com/mypantone-color-app-android) or [iOS](https://www.pantone.com/studio)

Doing it manually, also go to YouTube to get "Suggested Videos" on the right column.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHvfVc_8eMc

To grab a specific color and find out which paint chip matches it try the [Valspar site](https://www.askval.com/PhotoMatch).

Answer (score 0):

Marcus Hyde shoots 35 and 120mm film. You can get close to a film look with post processing (it seems like you’re into IG so VSCO might have filters you’d like), but getting that look requires film and flash. (may have already been linked to but: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4FtIKNmNXw&app=desktop )