# How can I achieve this brownish look?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, tone

I've been trying to achieve this look for some time, but I'm stuck :(. Starting with the camera, I heard that maybe adjusting the WB to cloudy? And the metering to spot metering?

I mainly use Lightroom and I just can't get it right. I see they use a very brownish tone, taking down a lot of saturation in the greens but the skin colors look really good. I would be very happy for any kind of tips.

[image: examples of the brown-tinted look (wedding images)]
[image: more examples of the brown-tinted look (wedding images)]

Comment: Whose images are those? Did you upload them to imgur? Is that ok with the original content creator? Welcome to the site and thank you for asking a good question and even including example images. But please be careful not to break any copyright. It might be safer to just link to where you found those images online, even if those links might break in the future. At the very least, link to the website of the photographer. After all, you seem to be admiring the work.

Comment: With the exception of brown vs. red is this a duplicate question: [How to get the film or reddish type of look?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97022/how-to-get-the-film-or-reddish-type-of-look/97024#97024)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve a retro-elegant, faded, low-contrast look?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99004/how-to-achieve-a-retro-elegant-faded-low-contrast-look)

Comment: [How to I edit a photo to have a old vintage look?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39546/75526); [How can this brightly colored yet gentle pastel-color effect be achieved?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46592/75526)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  In Lightroom, you can use the "Split Toning" tool.

[image: Split Toning in the Lightroom Develop module]

There are color selection boxes next to the word "Highlights" and "Shadows".  Pick these and you can select a color cast (I picked a sand tone) and this will give the image a decidedly "brown" cast.

You can also desaturate (up in the basic adjustments).  I found that desaturating to around -15 to -20 units created a pleasantly subdued look.

[image: Before/After split-toning & desaturation]

I find the look I used in this example to be a bit heavy-handed on the brown tone (my preference is to be a bit more subtle) but the example makes it easy to see what I'm doing here.

You can experiment with the hue selection and saturation level in split-toning (as well as overall desaturation) to achieve the look you want.

Another alternative is to try Lightroom profile presets.  In the "Basic" adjustment pane you'll find the "Profile" selection (it typically defaults to "Adobe Standard").  There's an icon that has a grid of 4 rectangles ... click the icon and it will open the profile presets.  You can try those to see if you find a look that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this warm look.

You can make a selection with lightroom and then adjust either the color temp or color balance.  Or, you could apply split toning where the highlights are a warm tone while shadows are cool or neutral or whatever color you want.

You can also use the color picker tool to adjust specific colors.

You can do this in camera simply by using a KR3 or 81A filter, but this will apply a warming affect to the entire image.  To do this in camera but selectively, you would need to use a light modifier such as a reflector with some kind of gold or warm-toned material.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that you need know the color wheel, any oposite colour will give you that brownish style. you can proceed by colour calibration module in lightroom or split toning module. play with the saturation after. that